# Location Manager Stops Updating Randomly

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-location, cllocationmanager, locationmanager

I'm writing an app that uses **CoreLocation**, and for some reason the location manager randomly stops updating the location.

I've made sure that all calls to the `startUpdating` method are on the main thread (not sure that it even matters).

I have logged all the delegate methods, including `didAuthorizationStatusChange`, `didPauseUpdatingLocation`, `didFailWithError` and have found that none are called.

It seems to stop after 4 updates; why does this happen?

**UPDATE**: a call to `startUpdating` from the `applicationDidFinish` works, but a call to the method later in code stops working once again

```
-(CLLocationManager*) locationManager
{
if(locationManager == nil)
{
        locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
        locationManager.delegate = self;
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
        locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
}

return locationManager;
}


[self.locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:self.venueRegion];
```

Answer (score -2):

Couple of things.

You have written a custom singleton getter, except its not static (should be a + sign in front of the getter), that seems off. Getting the location manager should look like this:

CLLocationManager *myManager =  [MyLocationManager sharedManager];

Next, if that is a "Getter" method, it should be:

-(CLLocationManager*)getLocationManager;

Otherwise, when you hit self.locationManager, you are not going through your getter and triggering the necessary getter operations you are trying to hit here.

Comment: Thats not the problem, properties in objc get accessors setVarName and varName.  I do agree that the singleton mite be wrong, but it seems alloc a single instance no problem